# YCSB sinusoidal workload for cassandra cluster

Tags: cassandra, ycsb, elasticity

I am using ycsb to test a visual's cassandra cluster behavior.
Is there a sinusoidal workload? I have not found such an option at Core Workloads.
I would like to increase the throughput sinusoidal and then measure latency and cache sizes of the cluster.
Also at ycsb output file can I have more metrics than the current available? Now I can only see throughput and latency but I would like to measure cache sizes of the nodes also.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no other, undocumented, workload. If you want to use other workloads, you could:

1. Modify YCSB to issue the workload you want (it is not that hard).
2. Use [KV-replay](https://github.com/ebozag/KV-replay) to replay a synthetic workload (trace file). You can create this file with python or your language of preference, and then replay it with YCSB-replay.

Comment: @Hobowpen Please accept the answer if it was what you were looking for.